# I am seeing new Triality questions seemingly copy pasted on Stack Overflow. Intended?

Tags: discussion, spam, spam-seeds

Here is [an example low-quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73506701) and the verbatim one on Triality.

The Stack Overflow question is all title with an advertisement body:

[image: Image of question]

The answers also read like advertising for the site with another advertising link at the bottom:

[image: Image of answer]

I couldn't find any questions here about Triality questions. So should they be allowed? Downvoted? Are they doing this via an API or an app to automate duplicating the questions?

One just showed in my review workflow. Until I know more about them, I'll <kbd>Skip</kbd> them.

Comment: If you look at all that users content, it's *all* copied; you should be flagging the content with a custom moderator flag.

Comment: If nothing else, none of their content meets the requirements in the [help] article [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing); if it was a one off, I'd consider it good faith and edit it to improve that one post and leave a comment. This is just malicious plagiarism.

Comment: Quoting my edit revision (as people don't always read them): *"As these have been marked as spam, I felt it wise to change these to images, so as not to further promote the content,"*

Comment: Surprise, surprise, the kind of people who are interested in a grifting pyramid scheme also don't show proper respect for the site rules...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Larnu more or less answered this in the comments; there are enough answers, and the whole lot are blatantly plagiarised. There's also no disclosure, qualifying them as spam. Same with the questions, but that's just one part of it.

Several of the questions are also really, really low quality. The one you linked doesn't meet any of the quality requirements. If it's an isolated incident, a close vote/flag is enough. In this case, it wasn't.

In this case, there was excessive promotion, which is worthy of a spam flag. If you stumble into similar users though, it's often a good idea to mod flag to provide this type of context. I'll argue that most or all mods would look into context when presented with spam flags on Q&A pairs like these. Now, in general, from just a single question, we often assume good faith and nudge the user in a direction of better questions/answers. However, with 9 Q&A pairs promoting the site, accounting for 100% of the user's combined posts, we're solidly past assuming good faith.

To answer some of your specific questions:

> I couldn't find any questions here about Triality questions. So should be be allowed?

The exact platform is irrelevant; plagiarising questions from any other platform, or from other questions on Stack Overflow, is a violation of our [referencing guidelines](/help/referencing), particularly:

> Do not copy the complete text of sources; instead, use their words and ideas to support your own

and

> Always give proper credit to the author and site where you found the text, including a direct link to it.

All the answers and questions qualify as plagiarism under the first category, but it's backed up by the second, because of incorrect citations.

However, as I also mentioned earlier, a user mass-posting plagiarised questions and answers with incorrect citations, no disclosure, and only doing that, this also qualifies under [our definition of spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), which is how the questions and answers have been treated in this case.

> Downvoted?

You can, but preferably not as the only thing you do. Flags help us mods discover and handle these, but downvotes do not. 6 spam or R/A flags (in any combination, as long as there's 6 total) cast by the community is enough to destroy the post as well, without needing mod intervention. In general though, our response times on spam flags are low, because it's a low-volume queue, it's high visibility, and high priority.

There's also a community-driven organization [dedicated to fighting spam](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/11540/charcoal-hq), where posts like these can be reported, or usually discussed if you're in doubt.

> Are they doing this via an API or an App to automate duplicating the question?

This is something I can't answer (not because I'm not allowed to; I simply have no idea, and can't find any obvious indicators in the mod tools), but it doesn't particularly matter; automated or not, it's plagiarism and excessive promotion in one convenient package, and it has to go. Automated answering in general is a subject onto itself, and one I believe we've already discussed elsewhere on meta, in relation to GitHub <s>Plagiarist</s> [Copilot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub_Copilot).

Comment: Only one spelling of plagiarised is correct. The other is plagiarized. (Moderator Note: This is a joke.)

Comment: Did you guys attempt to contact Larnu before suspending his account?  Suspension is a very disruptive act, and this kind of posting is the result of a common misunderstanding among vendors about how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey excuse me? We have most certainly [not suspended Larnu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) (this comment will not age well; screenshot for future reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqbo7.png -- note the glaring lack of a suspension banner)

Comment: @Zoe: Sorry, wrong user. https://stackoverflow.com/users/19802857/espejelomar

Comment: I would *guess* it's a similar scenario to when a user gets a review ban @RobertHarvey ; the idea is to ensure that the user *see's* the ban by them trying to further do something that they have been using incorrectly. As it was clear malicious intent, I would argue that stopping them from further making bad contributions first, and then letting them know seems the more prudent solution.